# When printing outputs an empty line appears before my outputs

Tags: python, combinations

I have attempted to write a program which asks the user for a string and a number (On the same line) and then prints all possible combinations of the string up to the size of the number. The output format should be: All capitals, Each combination on each line, Length of combination(Shortest First) and in alphabetical.

My code outputs the right combinations in the right order but it places an empty before the outputs and I'm not sure why.

```
from itertools import combinations
allcombo = []
S = input().strip()
inputlist = S.split()
k = int(inputlist[1])
S = inputlist[0]

#
for L in range(0, k+1):
    allcombo = []

    for pos in combinations(S, L):

        pos = sorted(pos)
        pos = str(pos).translate({ord(c): None for c in "[]()', "})
        allcombo.append(pos) 
        allcombo = sorted(allcombo)  
    print(*allcombo, sep = '\n')
```

Input:

```
HACK 2
```

Output:

```
(Empty Line)
A
C
H
K
AC
AH
AK
CH
CK
HK
```

Also I've only been coding for about a week so if anyone would like to show me how to write this properly, I'd be very pleased.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the line:

```
for L in range(0, k+1) # Notice that L is starting at 0.
```

Now, observe this line:

```
for pos in combinations(S, L)
```

So, we will have the following during our first iteration of the inner for loop:

```
for pos in combinations(S, 0) # This is an empty collection during your first loop.
```

Basically no work is being performed inside your loop because there is nothing to iterate over, and you will just being printing an empty string.

Change the following code:

```
for L in range(0, k+1)
```

to this:

```
for L in range(1, k+1) # Skips the empty collection since L starts at 1.
```

and this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks very much @stungkit, this worked perfectly now. I was wondering if this was a bad way of writing the code of if something else would have been more efficient or coherent.

Comment: Your code makes sense. However, I am not sure why you need pos = str(pos).translate({ord(c): None for c in "[]()', "}) and allcombo = sorted(allcombo). I suggest taking them out.

Comment: I was trying to print the combinations without any other formatting and in that order. Is there an easier way of doing this?